# Configure persistence.xml JPA

Tags: xml, jpa, netbeans, eclipselink, one-to-many

I want to configure persistence.xml file for OneToMany relation.My IDE is NetBeans.  My persistence is like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <!-- Will be referenced in Spring Context File -->
  <persistence-unit name="jpa-persistence" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <class>co.trainingproject.models.User</class>
    <class>co.trainingproject.models.Category</class>
    <class>co.trainingproject.models.Topic</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/trainingdb"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="123456"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And Category.java:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "idcategory", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Topic> topiclist;
```

And Topic.java:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "idcategory", referencedColumnName = "idcategory")
private Category idcategory;
```

ApplicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">
    <!-- Enable Spring Annotation Configuration -->
    <context:annotation-config />
    <!-- Scan for all of Spring components such as Spring Service -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="co.trainingproject"></context:component-scan>

    <!-- Necessary to get the entity manager injected into the factory bean -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" /> 

    <!-- Define EclipseLink JPA Vendor Adapter -->
    <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="databasePlatform"
            value="org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.MySQLPlatform" />
        <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
        <property name="showSql" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Define Hibernate JPA Vendor Adapter -->
    <!-- <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="databasePlatform"
            value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
    </bean>  -->

    <!-- Entity Manager Factory -->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="jpa-persistence"></property>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Transaction Manager -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Detect @Transactional -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
</beans>
```

I think another setting is needed in these files, because when I want to deploy my project in glassfish, this error occurred:

```
Exception Occurred :Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'categoryService': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is Exception [EclipseLink-30005] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException
Exception Description: An exception was thrown while searching for persistence archives with ClassLoader: WebappClassLoader (delegate=true; repositories=WEB-INF/classes/)
```

Comment: Here few thing that you should check 
1. Is CategoryService comes under package "co.trainingproject".
2. Is CategoryService annotated with @Component or equivalent.

Comment: Yes,I have a package named: co.trainingproject.services that includes some service classes. @eatSleepCode

Answer (score 0):

This bug is related to NetBeans. Look [this.](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=243034)
I wrote in glassfish4/bin this:

```
./asadmin add-resources ~/NetBeansProjects/../web/WEB-INF/glassfish-resources.xml
```